# Gridx: How to keep selections over multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, gridx

I am currently encountering the following problem:

I have a paged grid that consists of 5 pages. The user needs to select certain rows within that grid, while navigating through all of the 5 pages (some selections on page 1, some on page 2, etc.).

How can I ensure that the user´s selection from page 1 won´t "disappear", once the user navigated on to another page?
The way I currently have it set up, once the user clicks on page 2, the selections from page 1 are gone.

Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What if you append the currently selected rows to an array when you go to another page?

Comment: @ChrisWissmach that's ok, but i don't know how to keep selected appear when i back to the previous page.